# How to achieve the tar file with a specific directory structure inside it using Python

Tags: python, tar, gzip, archiving

I have a directory structure with many log files.

Example:

```
root/feature1/pre/a.log<br>
root/feature1/pre/b.log<br>
root/feature1/post/c.log<br>
root/feature1/post/d.og<br>
root/feature2/pre/e.log<br>
root/feature2/pre/f.log<br>
root/feature2/post/g.log<br>
root/feature2/post/h.log
```

I want to archive few of the log files with the condition that log files are older than 2 months. I could archive the log files with the given condition but couldn't maintain directory inside tar file.

I need :
root/archive.tar.gz

Where archive.tar.gz contains

```
feature1/pre/a.log
feature1/post/d.log
feature2/pre/e.log
feature2/post/g.log
feature2/post/h.log
```

Here, a.log, d.log, e.log, g.log, h.log files are the ones older than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Linux problem than Python.  I suggest using the **find** command with file name and file time options.  Pass those names into the **tar** command you're using, something like

```
tar -czf archive `find /root -name feature*.log -ctime +60`
```

Test this on your command line; when it works as you want, then use Python's **os** package to execute it from your Python script.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I think I should have explained you better. I want to achieve multiple archives such that each archive contains one week's log. So the logic you explained me gives me a single archive. I am trying to write a code in python which reads all the folders and archives it in a weekly basis. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to retain directory structure inside each archive.

Comment: I still don't understand, then -- keeping separate archives is a matter of concatenating a time stamp into the archive name.  The tar ball still includes the directory structure, in that it includes the full path of each archived file.